# Djikstra algorithm analysis

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, shortest-path

My textbook says that the Dijkstra algorithm's runtime is  $O(n) + O(m \log(n)) = O((n+m) \log(n))$. How did they come up with that?

Dijkstra algorithm pseudocode:

```
 1. Dijkstra(V, E, s):
 2.    Create an empty priority queue

 3.    for each v ≠ s:
 4.        d(v) ← ∞
 5.        d(s) ← 0

 6.    for each v ∈ V:
 7.        insert v with key d(v) into priority queue

 8.    while (the priority queue is not empty):
 9.        u ← delete-min from priority queue

10.        For each edge (u,v) ∈ E leaving u:
11.            If d(v) > d(u) + l(u,v):
12.                decrease-key of v to d(u) + l(u,v) in priority queue
13.                d(v) ← d(u) + l(u,v)
```

My runtime analysis:

```
 1.
 2. O(1)

 3. O(n)
 4.     O(1)
 5.     O(1)

 6. O(n)
 7.     O(log(n))

 8. O(n)
 9.     O(log(n))

10.     O(m)
11.         O(1)
12.             O(log(n))
13.             O(1)
```

From my analysis, the largest runtime would be from lines 8, 10, 11, and 12, resulting in $O(nm\log(n)) \ne O((n+m) \log(n))$.

Comment: For reference, could you include your book's name?

Comment: What analysis does _the book_ give? Have you checked other sources? Dijkstra is utterly standard and analysed in about every AofA book. What you give there is an indented list of O-terms, not an analysis; have you tried [a principled approach](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)?

Comment: NB: Dijkstra's algorithm is _not_ greedy.

Answer (score 1):

```
 8.    while (the priority queue is not empty):
 9.        u ← delete-min from priority queue

10.        For each edge (u,v) ∈ E leaving u:
11.            If d(v) > d(u) + l(u,v):
12.                decrease-key of v to d(u) + l(u,v) in priority queue
13.                d(v) ← d(u) + l(u,v)
```

Consider the multi-set of all edges that appear on line 10, where $u$ goes through all vertices thanks to the line 9 inside the while loop. There are two cases.

- The graph is undirected. Each of those edges must be incident to a vertex $u$. So each edge in the graph appears exactly twice.
- The graph is directed. Each of those edges must have $u$ as its starting endpoint. So each edge in the graph exactly appears once.

So in total, the number of edges that appear on line 10 is either $2|E|$ with undirected graph or $|E|$ with directed graph. So the running time from lines 8, 10, 11, and 12 is $2mO(\log(n))$ or $mO(\log(n))$. That is, $O(m\log(n))$.

Had the line 10 been `For each edge (w,v) ∈ E:`, your analysis might have had a chance to be correct.